# Шифр Цезаря для кириллицы

Tags: c++, linux, utf-8, fstream

Здравствуйте! Появилась надобность написать программу на С++, шифрующую русские строки, считываемые из файла с кодировкой UTF-8. Использую STL wstring.
В случае с обычным вводом с экрана всё работало бы корректно: я просто менял бы номера символов на K единиц и получал бы другие символы. Проблема состоит в том, что при данном коде:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
    wfstream f("in.txt", fstream::in);
    wstring tmp;
    f >> tmp;
    wcout << tmp.size() << ": " << tmp << endl;
}
```

строка оказывается пустой. Появлялась идея считать в обычный string, а затем преобразовать в wstring - функция wstring_convert не определена. Код компилирую на g++ 4.8 в ОС Linux Mint 17.

UPD: хочется добавить, что при таком коде строка `f >> tmp` выбрасывает исключение:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure' 
basic_filebuf::underflow invalid byte sequence in file
```

Comment: вопрос можно редактировать

Comment: `wstring_convert не определена` — пробовали подключать заголовок [`<locale>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/locale)?

Comment: пробовал. к сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: Кстати, а почему используется `wstring`, а не, например, [`u16string`](https://ideone.com/N8Qplj)?

Comment: пытаюсь сделать, как Вы сказали, но не получается вывести результат. не подскажете, на что нужно заменить `cout`? порыскал в сети: для этого требуется преобразование через `wstring_convert`.

Comment: `wstring_convert` объявлена `deprecated` в C++17, наряду с аналогами. Думаю, это не просто так. А g++ 4.8 её скорее всего еще не поддерживает. Не проще ли использовать библиотеку для работы с utf8, например, эту: http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net ?

Comment: @PhilipLisitsyn, так в примере ведь в том числе показан и вывод: считываем в `string`, преобразуем в `u16string` с помощью функции `to16`, делаем некоторые преобразования с `u16string`, затем переводим её обратно в `string` с помощью функции `to8`, получившуюся `string` выводим.

Comment: дык в примере-то и используется `wstring_convert`, который не поддерживается моим компилятором.

Comment: Виктор, спасибо за альтернативное решение, но я хочу решить проблему своими руками. я использую Ваш вариант в крайнем случае.

Comment: Кажется, `wstring_convert` доступен [начиная с gcc 5.1](https://godbolt.org/g/ta73fv), так что ещё одним вариантом на крайний случай может быть [попытка обновить gcc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272423/199096).